# Как сделать get_post по категории или тэгу?

Tags: php, html, массивы, wordpress, запрос

В моей теме WP есть parallax-slider. Задача - выводить на разных страницах только определенные слайды из определенных категорий или с определенными тэгами. Слайдер является кастомным типом постов, все изображения слайдера получают в оригинальном файле slider.php с помощью следующего кода:

```
$args = array(     
    'post_type'        => 'slider',
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'orderby'          => $orderby,
    'order'            => $order,
    'suppress_filters' => $suppress_filters
                                             );'
$slides = get_posts( $args );`
```

далее данные из $slides передаются в этот цикл:

```
foreach( $slides as $k => $slide ) {



            $url                = get_post_meta($slide->ID, 'my_slider_url', true);
            $thumb_url          = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($slide->ID), 'slider-thumb');
            $sl_image_url       = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($slide->ID), 'full');
            $caption            = get_post_meta($slide->ID, 'my_slider_caption', true);
```

Я создал таксономию тэгов и категорий, выглядит вот так:

```
function my_post_type_slider() {
register_post_type( 'slider',
    array(
        'label'               => theme_locals("slides"),
        'singular_label'      => theme_locals("slides"),
        '_builtin'            => false,
        'exclude_from_search' => true, // Exclude from Search Results
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => false,
        'taxonomies'          => 'slider_tag',
        'rewrite' => array(
                        'slug'       => 'slide-view',
                        'with_front' => FALSE,
                    ),
        'query_var' => 'slider', // This goes to the WP_Query schema
        'menu_icon' => ( version_compare( $GLOBALS['wp_version'], '3.8', '>=' ) ) ? 'dashicons-slides' : PARENT_URL . '/includes/images/icon_slides.png',
        'supports'  => array(
                            'title',
                            'thumbnail',
                            'page-attributes',
                        )
    )
);

 register_taxonomy(
    'slider_category',
    'slider',
    array(
        'hierarchical'  => true,
        'label'         => theme_locals("categories"),
        'singular_name' => theme_locals("category"),
        'rewrite'       => true,
        'query_var'     => true
    )
```

);

```
 register_taxonomy(
    'slider_tag',
    'slider',
    array(
        'hierarchical'  => false,
        'label'         => theme_locals("tags"),
        'singular_name' => theme_locals("tag"),
        'rewrite'       => true,
        'query_var'     => true
    )



       );
```

}
     add_action('init', 'my_post_type_slider');'

Но как я не пробую сделать get_posts добавляя в аргументы category_name => 'имя_категории' или tag => 'имя тага' или любым другим способом каким только не пробывал - переменная slides - пустая...

Как можно сделать данное действие с помощью get_posts? Если делать с помощью WP-query то переменная не пустая, но придется переделывать обработчик, повторюсь задача - выводить слайды только с определенной категории, не весь пост.

Comment: а вы сами таксомии проверяли что они выдают ?

Comment: $category = get_terms( 'slider_category', $args );
print_r ($tags); Выходит на экранчике массив

Comment: ну и какие данные получаете ?

Comment: минута, счас выведу

Comment: Array ( [0] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 46 [name] => 123 [slug] => 123 [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 46 [taxonomy] => slider_category [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 3 [filter] => raw ) )

используеться категория 123

Comment: по другому не знаю как проверить - еще таксы есть в админке, можно выполнить команду выше. но get_posts не работает

Answer (score 1):

Извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, неправильно прописал аргументы в запросе, конкретнее tax_query. Вот рабочий код:

```
$args = array(
'numberposts'=>-1,
'post_type'=>'slider',
'exclude'=>$the_id,
'tax_query'=>array(array('taxonomy'=>'slider_tag',
            'field'=>'slug',
            'terms'=>$slug_name,
            ))
);  
$slides = get_posts( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте

```
$args = array( 
    'category'         => $tags->term_id,
    'post_type'        => 'slider',
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'orderby'          => $orderby,
    'order'            => $order,
    'suppress_filters' => $suppress_filters
                                             );'
$slides = get_posts( $args );`
```

Comment: извините, я не очень понял - в переменную $tags или term_id - какие-то значения сюда помещать надо?
если нет - то пока выдает все слайды как обычно..

Comment: глупость спросил, в $tags = get_terms( 'slider_category', $args ); пока также... все слайды, не выбирает отдельные пробую дальше

Comment: попробовал разные вариации - все так же выдает все слайды,

Comment: разобрался - затупил с tax_query